# Populating list with user selected criteria MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a table with a lot of data and I allow the user to specify which data they want to have displayed in a table (I am using Multi select lists).

**Scenario Example**(Below is an example and not related to my data or fields, this is just to keep things simple)

My table contains the following Columns with data:

```
FirstName, Surname, DOB, Address1, Address2, Address3, JobPosition, Age
```

The user then can select between an age range(ex. 18 - 30) and the type of position(Receptionist). The user then selects which fields it would like to see, example FirstName, Surname, JobPosition, Age (These are stored in a string array) -  Now my problem is, I need to only display these headings in a table with its data, not Address1, 2 and 3.

So if I had to write a query of what it should then look like:

```
SELECT FirstName, Surname, Position, Age, WHERE age between 18 and 30 and JobPosition = 'Receptionist'
```

I am using LINQ and C# - I have the query and everything set up, which would look something like this:

```
var query = db.people.where(x=>(x.age >= 18 && x.age <= 30) && x.JobPosition == "Receptionist").ToList();
```

How do I only pull through those specifically selected headings and display them in a table in my view?

I have searched high and low, but struggling to find something that I know should be relatively simple to do.

**Adding my actual ActionResult to give you an idea of what im doing**

```
public ActionResult GetReport(ReportKPIViewModel model)
{
    clsReportKPI clsReportKPI = new clsReportKPI();
    List<ReportKPIDetailsViewModel> ReportKPIDetails = new List<ReportKPIDetailsViewModel>(); //This contrains a few specific fields

    try
    {
        var TLGUIDs = clsReportKPI.GetTeamLeaderOpsGUIDs(model.TeamLeadersArray); //This returns The specific selected users GUID's from User Table
        var QAGUIDs = clsReportKPI.GetQualityAuditorGUIDs(model.QualityAuditorsArray); //This returns The specific selected users GUID's from User Table
        var AgentGUIDs = clsReportKPI.GetAgentGUIDs(model.AgentsArray); //This returns The specific selected users GUID's from User Table
        var KPIQAFields = clsReportKPI.GetKPIQAFields(model.KPIArray); //This returns The specific selected fields that the user wants displayed - This is an IENumerable<string>

        var qualityAudit = db.QualityAudits.Where(x => x.AreaId == model.AreaFilterId && TLGUIDs.Contains(x.TeamLeaderOpsId) && QAGUIDs.Contains(x.AuditorId) && AgentGUIDs.Contains(x.AgentId)).ToList(); //This is returning all data in the table related to the criteria the user selected

        foreach(var item in qualityAudit)
        {
            ReportKPIDetailsViewModel RKPI = new ReportKPIDetailsViewModel();

            RKPI.Date = item.QualityAuditDate;
            RKPI.AreaName = item.Area.AreaName;
            RKPI.TeamLeader = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == item.TeamLeaderOpsId).FullName;
            RKPI.QualityAuditor = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == item.AuditorId).FullName;
            RKPI.Agent = item.Agent.FirstName.ToString() + " " + item.Agent.LastName.ToString();

            ReportKPIDetails.Add(RKPI);
        }

        model.KPIColumnNames = KPIQAFields; // These are the columns the user selected
        model.ReportKPIDetails = ReportKPIDetails;

        return PartialView("_partialReports", model);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //model.ReportKPIDetails = ReportDetailsList;

        return PartialView("_partialReports", model);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, thanks to everyone who passed a comment and tried helping! I was expecting a much less friendlier/helpful response, due to my format of question.

I have however found a solution to my problem. To give a quick description of what I did :

- Gathered all criteria via front end and passed to my Linq query and pulled all data within the table into a List<>
- Created a function that converts my List<> to a DataTable(Here I specified which compulsary fields I wanted shown as well as the fields the user selected, to know which data to put in the datatable.
- This I passed to my view and displayed the information.

I know this is relatively custom, but perhaps it helps someone else. Below is all my code :

**Controller:**
//This is the actionresult hit after clicking the submit button

```
public ActionResult GetReport(ReportKPIViewModel model)
        {
            clsReportKPI clsReportKPI = new clsReportKPI();
            List<ReportKPIDetailsViewModel> ReportKPIDetails = new List<ReportKPIDetailsViewModel>();
            List<string> CompulsaryFields = new List<string>();

            CompulsaryFields.Add("Date");
            CompulsaryFields.Add("AreaName");
            CompulsaryFields.Add("TeamLeaderName");
            CompulsaryFields.Add("QualityAuditorName");
            CompulsaryFields.Add("AgentName");

            try
            {
                var TLGUIDs = clsReportKPI.GetTeamLeaderOpsGUIDs(model.TeamLeadersArray);
                var QAGUIDs = clsReportKPI.GetQualityAuditorGUIDs(model.QualityAuditorsArray);
                var AgentGUIDs = clsReportKPI.GetAgentGUIDs(model.AgentsArray);
                var KPIQAFields = clsReportKPI.GetKPIQAFields(model.KPIArray);

                var qualityAudit = db.QualityAudits.Where(x => (DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.QualityAuditDate) >= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(model.ReportDateFrom) && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(x.QualityAuditDate) <= DbFunctions.TruncateTime(model.ReportDateTo)) &&  x.AreaId == model.AreaFilterId && TLGUIDs.Contains(x.TeamLeaderOpsId) && QAGUIDs.Contains(x.AuditorId) && AgentGUIDs.Contains(x.AgentId)).ToList();

                foreach (var item in qualityAudit)
                {
                    item.Date = item.QualityAuditDate;
                    item.AreaName = item.Area.AreaName;
                    item.TeamLeaderName = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == item.TeamLeaderOpsId).FullName;
                    item.QualityAuditorName = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == item.AuditorId).FullName;
                    item.AgentName = item.Agent.FirstName.ToString() + " " + item.Agent.LastName.ToString();
                }

                DataTable dt = LINQToDataTable(qualityAudit, CompulsaryFields, KPIQAFields);

                model.KPIColumnNames = KPIQAFields;
                model.ReportKPIDetails = ReportKPIDetails;
                model.dtReportDetails = dt;

                return PartialView("_partialReports", model);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //model.ReportKPIDetails = ReportDetailsList;

                return PartialView("_partialReports", model);
            }
        }
```

//This is the function used to convert my List<> to a datatable:

```
public DataTable LINQToDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> varlist, List<string> CompulsaryFields, IEnumerable<string> QAFields)
        {
            DataTable dtReturn = new DataTable();
            // column names 
            PropertyInfo[] oProps = null;

            if (varlist == null) return dtReturn;

            foreach (T rec in varlist)
            {
                // Use reflection to get property names, to create table, Only first time, others 
                //will follow
                if (oProps == null)
                {
                    oProps = ((Type)rec.GetType()).GetProperties();
                    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in oProps)
                    {
                        Type colType = pi.PropertyType;

                        if ((colType.IsGenericType) && (colType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
                        == typeof(Nullable<>)))
                        {
                            colType = colType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                        }

                        foreach(var item in CompulsaryFields)
                        {
                            if (pi.Name == item)
                            {
                                dtReturn.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(pi.Name, colType));
                            }
                        }

                        foreach (var item in QAFields)
                        {
                            if (pi.Name == item)
                            {
                                dtReturn.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(pi.Name, colType));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                DataRow dr = dtReturn.NewRow();

                foreach (PropertyInfo pi in oProps)
                {
                    foreach (var item in CompulsaryFields)
                    {
                        if (pi.Name == item)
                        {
                            dr[pi.Name] = pi.GetValue(rec, null) == null ? DBNull.Value : pi.GetValue(rec, null);
                        }
                    }

                    foreach (var item in QAFields)
                    {
                        if (pi.Name == item)
                        {
                            dr[pi.Name] = pi.GetValue(rec, null) == null ? DBNull.Value : pi.GetValue(rec, null);
                        }
                    }

                }

                dtReturn.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            return dtReturn;
        }
```

**Partial View:**

```
@model [ApplicationName].ViewModels.ReportKPIViewModel

<style>
    td{
        white-space:nowrap;
    }
</style>

@if (Model.ReportKPIDetails != null)
{
    <div class="panel panel-success">
        <div class="panel-heading panel-title"><strong>KPI Report Results</strong></div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div style="overflow:auto">
                <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover">
                    <tr style="background-color: #00b8ce; color: white;">
                        @foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in Model.dtReportDetails.Columns)
                        {
                            <th>@col.ColumnName</th>
                        }
                    </tr>

                    @foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in Model.dtReportDetails.Rows)
                {
                        <tr>
                            @foreach (var cell in row.ItemArray)
                            {
                                <td>
                                    @cell.ToString()
                                </td>
                            }
                        </tr>
                    }
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you would like to consume your data you will require to project your data into either a strongly typed object or if you are lucky you can use a dynamic type.

`var query = db.people.where(x=>(x.age >= 18 && x.age <= 30) && x.JobPosition == "Receptionist").Select(a=> new {FirstName =a.FirstName, LastName = a.LastName, Age = a.age, JobPosition = a.JobPosition}).ToList();`

The projection of the select should take care of it.

I have no idea how your class or object looks like, so you will have to fix up the code with the appropriate property naming.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Spook! I unfortunately have no control over what fields the user wants to select, so I wont be able to use this : .Select(a=> new {FirstName =a.FirstName, LastName = a.LastName, Age = a.age, JobPosition = a.JobPosition} : I some how need to dynamically fill a list and pass to my view, but this is where I am not sure how to. My class would contain all the fields, but displaying the specifically selected fields in a table is another story. Or Am I missing the plot ?

Comment: What I suggest is get all the data using linq and display only needed field in view conditionally. You obviously having some condition to check to display field.

Comment: I provided my actual actionresult. Perhaps this gives more perspective. I have been able to display the "user selected columns" in the header of the table, but dont know how to get the info for those fields. Does this make sense ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create `ODataController`:

```
public class PeopleController : ODataController
{
    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<People> Get()
    {
        return db.people.AsQueryable();
    }
}
```

You can specify the list of fields you want to select:

```
GET /People?$select=FirstName,Surname,Age
```

And you will receive a response similar to that:

```
{
    "odata.metadata": "http://localhost/odata/$metadata#People&$select=FirstName,Surname,Age",
    "value": [
        { "FirstName": "FirstNameOne", "Surname": "SurnameOne", "Age": 42 },
        { "FirstName": "FirstNameTwo","Surname": "SurnameTwo","Age": 53 },
        ...
    ]
}
```

More info about OData can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint)

Comment: Thanks! I will look into it.